# What is the best way of implementing tagging system in C# (no database; no asp.net)?

Tags: c#, tagging

I found a couple of examples on implementing tagging systems with a database backend but not any on implementing it using just list and dictionaries. Can anyone give me a guide on how to implement this or point me to some online articles?

Comment: Explain more... "but not any on implementing it using just list and dictionaries" - at least give examples links to us...

Answer (score 1):

I think you either need a database backend or you'll have to come up with a way to store it yourself.

The things that it's tagging, how are they stored?

Answer (score 0):

if i am not wrong, List and Dictionary are in memory objects,  you need to store tags in in non-volatile storage. so that you can  reuse them. (either it may be File, Database, or even u can use xml ) .

Comment: Or he could use the Application class